# Symfony/Jquery Collection of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony

I have a web app in Symfony. When I have a collection of objects (A user has many addresses) I need to implement JavaScript/jQuery method to let the user add the number of addresses that he has (https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html).

The problem is that I want to **wrap every label and every input tags** with a particular div like `<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"></div>` but after several tries I can't do that. Can you help me ?

My code :

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="addressList" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(parent_form.addresses.vars.prototype)|e }}">

    </div>
</div>
```

The `{{ form_widget(parent_form.addresses.vars.prototype)|e }}` in `data-prototype="..."` generates this html :

```
<div id="AddChildStep1_child_addresses___name__">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label required" for="AddChildStep1_child_addresses___name___street1">Street1</label>
        <input type="text" id="AddChildStep1_child_addresses___name___street1" name="AddChildStep1[child][addresses][__name__][street1]" required="required" maxlength="100" pattern=".{5,}" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="AddChildStep1_child_addresses___name___street2">Street2</label>
        <input type="text" id="AddChildStep1_child_addresses___name___street2" name="AddChildStep1[child][addresses][__name__][street2]" maxlength="100" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="AddChildStep1_child_addresses___name___number">Number</label>
        <input type="number" id="AddChildStep1_child_addresses___name___number" name="AddChildStep1[child][addresses][__name__][number]" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="AddChildStep1_child_addresses___name___box">Box</label>
        <input type="number" id="AddChildStep1_child_addresses___name___box" name="AddChildStep1[child][addresses][__name__][box]" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="AddChildStep1_child_addresses___name___locality">Locality</label>
        <select id="AddChildStep1_child_addresses___name___locality" name="AddChildStep1[child][addresses][__name__][locality]" class="form-control">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="1">1080 - Molenbeek-Saint-Jean - BELGIUM</option>
            <option value="2">1060 - Saint-Gilles - BELGIUM</option>
            <option value="3">1050 - Ixelles - BELGIUM</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label required" for="AddChildStep1_child_addresses___name___addressType">Address type</label>
        <select id="AddChildStep1_child_addresses___name___addressType" name="AddChildStep1[child][addresses][__name__][addressType]" class="form-control">
            <option value="HOME">Home</option>
            <option value="WORK">Work</option>
            <option value="HOLIDAYS">Holidays</option>
            <option value="OTHER">Other</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then Symfony documentation propose this code to add an address :

```
var collectionHolder;

// Set up an "add address" link

var addAddressLink = $('<a href="#" class="add_address_link">Add address</a>');
var newLinkP = $('<p class="centered"></p>').append(addAddressLink);

function addAddressForm(collectionHolder, newLinkP){

    // Get the data prototype
    var prototype = collectionHolder.data('prototype');

    // get the new index
    var index = collectionHolder.data('index');

    // Replace '__name__' in the prototype's HTML
    //instead be a number based on how many items we have
    var newForm = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index);

    // Increase the index with one for the new item
    collectionHolder.data('index', index+1);

    //Display the form in the page nan li, before the "add address" link
    var newFormP = $('<div class="one-address"></div>').append(newForm);
    newLinkP.before(newFormP)
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // Get the div that holds the collection of addresses
    collectionHolder = $('div#addressList');

    // add the "add address" anchor
    collectionHolder.append(newLinkP);

    // Count the current form inputs
    // use that as the new index when inserting a new item
    collectionHolder.data('index', collectionHolder.find(':input').length);
    addAddressLink.on('click', function(e)
    {
        // Prevent the link from creating a "#" on the URL
        e.preventDefault();
        // add a new address form
        addAddressForm(collectionHolder, newLinkP);
    })
});
```

**I would like to wrap every label element and every input element (that is in a `div.one-address`) with `<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12></div>`.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always customise your form rendering, at any level. Here, you need to customise it for a particular twig. This [document](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#form-theming-in-twig) is your reference. You can choose `form_label` and `form_widget` blocks to overwrite as per your need.

```
{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block form_label %}
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12>
        {{- parent() -}}
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block form_widget %}
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12>
        {{- parent() -}}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

In above code `form` is the Form variable in the twig.

If you want only your collection fields to have a different structure, save them in a separate twig and include in main twig. Then, customise the included twig only.

PS : Code not tested.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks ! I did a custom `form_row` and it simplifies my life a lot!